# java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[] memory leak on ResourceManager

Tags: memory-leaks, resourcemanager

We had a cluster with CDH-5.11.0-1.cdh5.11.0.p0.34-el7 and SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904-el7

The ResourceManager would throw OOM exception and exit after 15 days, and left a file like yarn_yarn-RESOURCEMANAGER-0416ef018576621c2992469c034c0761_pid11312.hprof in the oom_heap_dump_dir.

We used Eclipse MAT to analyze this hprof file, and the resulte is as follows.[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo0I1.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U76Uo.png)

We are new to use hadoop and java, so any help will be very appreciated.

I just found a same problem in 
[ResourceManager Memory Leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861974/resourcemanager-memory-leak)
but nobody answerd...